# Swift: how to make search bar animate when focused? Used to work?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Ok, I feel as though a few versions of Xcode ago this was the default, and I have it working in a past project, just do not know why I cant get this search bar animation to happen with this search bar now in Xcode 9.

What I want to happen is when the search bar ISNT focused, the placeholder text is centered:

[image]

Then when its tapped and becomes first responder, the text is left aligned (the transition between the two seems to animate automatically):

[image]

I swear search bars used to do this without any customization. How can I achieve this? Right now in my tableview custom header I set up my search bar programmatically like this:

```
searchBar.placeholder = "Find an Episode."
        searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        searchBar.barTintColor = thirdColorStr
        searchBar.tintColor = thirdColorStr
        searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: screenSize.height * (40/screenSize.height))
        self.addSubview(searchBar)
//        searchBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: (searchBar.bounds.height/2))
        searchBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: (searchBar.bounds.height)*0.8)
        searchBar.delegate = listVC

        for subView in searchBar.subviews {
            for subViewOne in subView.subviews {

                if let textField = subViewOne as? UITextField {

                    subViewOne.backgroundColor = secondColorStr
                    //print("HEREE:", textField.bounds.width/screenSize.width)

                    //use the code below if you want to change the color of placeholder
                    if let t = textField.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
                    {
                        t.textColor = thirdColorStr
                        t.font = iphoneFontThin
                        t.tintColor = thirdColorStr
                        t.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

                    }
//                    if let clearButton = textField.value(forKey: "_clearButton") as? UIButton {
//                        // Create a template copy of the original button image
//                        let img = UIImage(named: "clear")
//                        clearButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
//                        
//                        // Finally, set the image color
//                        //clearButton.tintColor = .red
//                    }
                    if let t = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
                    {
                        t.textColor = barColorStr
                        t.font = iphoneFontThin
                        t.backgroundColor = secondColorStr
```

Then

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        resetCategory(newCat: overallCategory)
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder() //kills keyboard
    }
```

I cant find any differences between the code that produces and animation and the one above that does not.

Comment: iOS 11 search bars are always left-aligned

Comment: Any way to get around that? I want an animation